# What's a way to test this program remotely?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, cloud, virtual-desktop

What I'm trying to do is run a graphics test program 24/7, on a cloud computer. But the thing is, it needs to have fairly large, static screen resolution (not anamorphic as my monitor is small), and Windows 7. Services like Amazon seem to have anamorphic resolution, or no resolution at all unless someone is accessing.

One way I can think of is to rent a cloud VM, and run another VM in that, but most services don't supported nested virtualisation and it seems very complicated. It'd be great if there was a service where I could just rent a computer over the internet, and not a VM. I'd be glad to know of any other possible solutions. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but "questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers". Have a look at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: It's a broad question, not limited to services. I'm looking for a solution to a specific problem that I may not have thought of. And it's not opinion-based as there is a right or wrong answer. The solution either works or it doesn't.

Comment: If you think so, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1314539/edit) your question to become on-topic. Your title suggests right away that you need a service and that's not appropiate for Superuser. (broad questions don't belong here either.)

Comment: ok, I edited it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to migrate to a Windows Server VPS, prepare to pay for what you need, unless you provide the license yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I didn't know about that. Will it have a static screen resolution?